# Apache Tomcat directory access, restricted and accessible only by web application

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, tomcat

I have a Grails app. I want to move out all the images users upload to a directory outside of my web-app directory, somewhere else on the disk. Then I want to allow my application to serve them on pages but users can't access the directory. I know one way if to use an ImageController that reads the image and streams it to the view, but that has some trades-off such as caching. I was wondering if there is a way to allow apache to serve images from a local directory outside the web-app and restrict it to the app only.

Comment: Yes it is possible. I'll come back to this question in a couple of days and answer for real if it hasn't gotten an answer by then (I can only do casual answers for the moment and this needs some proper attention).

Answer (score 1):

I tried this, and it worked. But It also allows the client to access it since it only maps it. But again I appreciate if anyone can elaborate more and offer another solution that provides more control over how web app and users can access this area.

basically added this in Tomcat `/conf/server.xml` inside `<Host>` tag:

```
<Context docBase="/path/to/images" path="/images" />
```

Found out that someone answered something like what I needed here : [Simplest way to serve static data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812244/simplest-way-to-serve-static-data-from-outside-the-application-server-in-a-java)